# What's the meaning of 'flirt with' in this news title?

Tags: meaning

The following sentence is the title of [this news](https://www.mlb.com/news/yu-darvish-carries-no-hitter-to-seventh-vs-brewers):

> Yu flirts with no-no as Cubs continue tear

I looked for the Cambridge dictionary for 'flirt with' and I got this:

> to consider an idea or action briefly without being serious about it:

The no-no might mean no-hitter in baseball pitching. It means the pitcher, Yu was not getting hit. But the above meaning from the dictionary doesn't make much sense as Yu was serious with his pitching. He was not doing pitching casually but seriously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a *no-no* is baseball lingo for a *no-hitter*.

This usage of *flirt* is an idiomatic one that roughly means *get close to*:

> [flirt](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flirt)
> 3 : to come close to reaching or experiencing something — used with *with*
> // *flirting* with disaster
> (M-W)

In this case, Yu Darvish was close to achieving a no-hitter, but ultimately surrendered a "one-out solo homer to Justin Smoak" in the seventh.

---

<sub>*As a side note, I'm tempted to say it's a metaphorical usage of the dictionary entry you cited. His achieving a no-hitter was briefly considered, or it was briefly a possibility, before it was broken up in the seventh. This consideration/possibility isn't as serious in the earlier innings as it is in the later ones. But this metaphor might be a stretch.*</sub>